# Does $\{y\in \mathbb{R}^n:\operatorname{rank}((x,y,Ay))=2\}$ have zero Lebesgue measure?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, measure-theory, vector-spaces, lebesgue-measure

This is probably a simple question, but I need some help.

Consider a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a real $n\times n$ matrix $A$. I'm interested in the set of $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x,y,Ay$ are linearly dependent.

To rule out trivial cases when the vectors $x,y,Ay$ are linearly dependent for any $y$, I assume that:

1. $n>2$
2. $x\neq0$
3. $A$ that is not a scalar multiple of the identity matrix $I_n$
4. the column space of $aI_n-A$ is not spanned by $x$, for any real scalar $a$.

It seems to me that the set of $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x,y,Ay$ are linearly dependent should have zero $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Is this correct, and how would I go about proving this?

**My thinking so far:**

Let $M_x=I_n-xx'/(x'x)$ be the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}(x)$. What I need to do, I think, is to find the measure of the set of $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $M_x y$ and $M_x Ay$ are collinear, that is, the set of $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $M_x(aI_n-A)y=0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, for any fixed $a$, the set $$S_a=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:M_x(aI_n-A)y=0\},$$
has zero $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, because $M_x(aI_n-A)\neq0$ by the assumption I've made above that the column space of $aI_n-A$ is not spanned by $x$ for any real scalar $a$.

But does the set $$\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:M_x(aI_n-A)y=0 \text{ for some } a\in\mathbb{R} \},$$ (an uncountable union of the null spaces $S_a$ over $a$) have zero $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Comment: It may help to note that
$$
\{y:\operatorname{rank}((x,y,Ay))\leq 2\}
$$
is closed

Comment: What do you mean by "such that the $n\times 2$ matrices $(x,Ay)$ and $(y,Ay)$ have rank 2"? That they have rank $2$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$? It's impossible. If $A$ is invertible, then for $y=A^{-1}x$, $(x,Ay)$ has rank 1. If $A$ is not invertible, then for $y\in Ker(A)$, $(y,Ay)$ has rank 1.

Comment: @Litho thanks - I've revised the question - hope it makes sense now

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks but how do you see that $\{y:\operatorname{rank}((x,y,Ay))\leq 2\}$ is closed?

Comment: Maybe you can post this question to mathoverflow.net. Please post a link to question there, if you do. I would very much like to know the answer.

Comment: thanks - I'll try my luck [there](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/202907/lebesgue-measure-of-set-of-y-in-mathbbrn-such-that-x-y-ay-are-linearly-de).

Comment: The $n \times 3$ matrix $(x, y, Ay)$  has rank $\le 2$ iff the determinant of every $3 \times 3$ submatrix is $0$.  These determinants are continuous functions of $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The set of $y$ for which $(x,y,Ay)$ has rank $\le 2$ is an algebraic variety (the set where the determinants of all $3 \times 3$ submatrices are $0$), so it either has measure $0$ or is the whole space.  Thus in a counterexample, $(x,y,Ay)$ would have rank $\le 2$ for all $y \in \mathbb R^n$.

Suppose $x, A$ was a counterexample.  Then $Ux, UAU^{-1}$ would also be a counterexample for any invertible $n \times n$ matrix $U$.  Thus we can assume wlog $x$ is the unit vector $e_1$.  Writing (corresponding to the first entry and the other $n-1$) $$y = \pmatrix{y_1\cr u\cr},\ A = \pmatrix{a & b^T\cr c & D}$$
we have
$$ (x, y, Ay) = \pmatrix{1 & y_1 & a y_1 + b^T u \cr
0 & u &  y_1 c + D u}$$
This has rank $\le 2$ iff $(u, y_1 c + D u)$ has rank $\le 1$.  If that is the case for all $y$, it is in particular the case when $y_1 = 0$, i.e.
$(u, Du)$ has rank $\le 1$ for all $u$. That says $Du$ is always a scalar multiple of $u$.  Now if $D v = \alpha v$ and $D w = \beta w$ with $\beta \ne \alpha$ and $v, w$ nonzero, then $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent 
and $D (v + w) = \alpha v + \beta w$ is not a scalar multiple of $v+w$. 
So we must have $\beta = \alpha$, i.e. $D = d I$ for some scalar $d$.
Now $(u, y_1 c + D u) = (u, y_1 c + d u)$ has the same rank as $(u, y_1 c)$, so if this rank is always $\le 1$, we must have $c = 0$.
Now that leaves
$$ A = \pmatrix{a & b^T\cr 0 & dI},\ A - dI = \pmatrix{a-d & b^T\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$
which has its column space spanned by $x$, contrary to the assumption.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very grateful for such a clear explanation. In order for me to fully understand the structure of the problem, I was wondering if there is also a way to see directly that the set $\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:M_x(aI_n-A)y=0 \text{ for some } a\in\mathbb{R} \}$ in my question has measure 0 (with "directly" meaning without looking at $\operatorname{rank}((x,y,Ay))$) ?

Answer (score 1):

Even with the modification to the question, the answer is still no. Consider $A = cI+B$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ and $Im(B)$ is spanned by $x$. For such $A$, the vectors $x,y,Ay$ are always linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I meant to rule out any case when the column space of $aI_n-A$ is spanned by $x$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I have now added that condition in my question (hope that's OK) and have also explained my thinking so far

Answer (score 1):

Assume $n\geq 3$, since the other cases are trivial. Consider the $3\times n$ matrix
\begin{align*}
g = \begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ Ay
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then $\operatorname{rank} g = \operatorname{rank} gg^t$ is maximal iff $f(x, y) = \det gg^t$ is nonzero. With the conditions you give, there should be some $y$ such that $x, y,$ and $Ay$ are linearly independent, and hence $f(x, y) \not= 0$. Clearly $f = 0$ for $y = 0$. Thus $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial in the $x_i$ and $y_i$. The set of points where it vanishes thus has measure $0$. The last remark is a standard result, I think, but it's easy to prove by induction using the constant rank theorem.

Comment: It is a good idea to look at the determinant of $gg^t$. However, it is not clear at all why the set where $f$ vanishes has to be of measure $0$. How do you exclude singular points? With the constant rank theorem, how do you guarantee the rank is constant over the aforementioned set?

Comment: $g$ as defined now is not a matrix. Note $x$ and $y$ are column matrices.

Comment: @Hans: Take $x^t$ and $y^t$, then. It's just a matter of notation.

Comment: @Hans: $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial in the $x_i$ and $y_i$. Its derivative has maximal rank off a set of measure 0 (namely, the set where all of its partial derivatives vanish) by induction, and the constant rank theorem shows that $f$ vanishes on a set of measure $0$ elsewhere. There are some details to fill in, but they should be straightforward.

Comment: Would you please write out the details of your argument? I am still not clear about why "Its derivative has maximal rank off a set of measure 0 (namely, the set where all of its partial derivatives vanish) by induction" (inducting over $n$?), and why "the constant rank theorem shows that f vanishes on a set of measure $0$ elsewhere".  The original poser of the question does not appear to know this argument. Many others and I would benefit from your explicit proof.

Comment: @Hans: This question is already closed, so I don't want to get into the details here; feel free to start a new question if you'd like. (The constant rank part is at least easy to explain: Locally at nonsingular points, $f$ looks like a projection $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \to x_1$.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22932/discussion-between-hans-and-anomaly).